# Routing issues between virtual web server and exchange server

Tags: routing, centos6

So I've got a virtual web server running CentOS 6.3. Trying to build a mail application on a website that uses SMTP authentication on the (Windows) Exchange server but it keeps failing though the script is correct. Finally attempted to ping the Exchange server (public IP) from the web server but I don't even get the message that the destination host is unreachable - it just times out, which would explain the failure of the mail script. When I called the service provider for advice, they said to make sure to remove all but the main gateway on the web server, but there is only one gateway defined in the ifconfig-etho file. iptables is wide open (temporarily, until I resolve this issue). What other steps could I take to resolve this routing issue?

Editing to show traceroute results:

```
traceroute to 64.183.151.82 (64.183.151.82), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  65.61.111-113.ptr.tierpoint.com (65.61.111.113)  2.943 ms  2.972 ms  2.839 ms
2  63.131.228-186.ptr.tierpoint.com (63.131.228.186)  1.617 ms  1.654 ms  1.705 ms
3  br1-20g-po5.spkn.tierpoint.com (65.61.96.113)  2.703 ms  1.748 ms  2.608 ms
4  209.119.222.5 (209.119.222.5)  9.903 ms  10.124 ms  8.315 ms
5  216.156.1.105.ptr.us.xo.net (216.156.1.105)  9.189 ms  9.229 ms  9.282 ms
6  216.156.0.209.ptr.us.xo.net (216.156.0.209)  12.685 ms  14.723 ms  11.166 ms
7  ae0d0.cir1.seattle7-wa.us.xo.net (207.88.13.141)  10.186 ms  8.546 ms  8.190 ms
8  216.156.100.70.ptr.us.xo.net (216.156.100.70)  9.775 ms  8.171 ms  8.332 ms
9  bu-ether12.sttswa5801w-bcr01.tbone.rr.com (66.109.6.148)  10.414 ms  10.303 
   ms 10.320 ms
10  107.14.16.103 (107.14.16.103)  30.003 ms  30.524 ms  29.317 ms
11  tge0-3-0.mscwid-rtr1.natnow.rr.com (65.28.218.1)  28.886 ms  28.822 ms  29.738 ms
12  CPE-65-28-217-30.kc.res.rr.com (65.28.217.30)  23.884 ms  24.901 ms  25.214 ms
13  ge-5-0-0-0.CRALIDFS1CW.pw.twcbiz.com (64.183.142.228)  24.140 ms  25.438 ms  
    25.514 ms
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
```

Comment: You don't really provide enough information about the network layout. Are both servers on the same private network or do they both just have public IP addresses? Are you using any NAT?

Comment: We're both on the same private network. Web server has no internal NIC and is not using NAT. I didn't ask the exchange server admin if he's using NAT but I doubt it.

Comment: Either your web server doesn't have a route to the Exchange server or there's a firewall blocking your connection. Can you run a trace route from the web server to the Exchange server and post the results?

Comment: Nobody can read these comments in the format in which they're in. Post the results to your question as a code sample or block quote.

Comment: Edited my question to show the results - sorry I didn't think of that. Obviously I'm new here.

Comment: Can you telnet from your Web server to your Exchange server on port 25?  When you say "same private network", do you mean they're on the same subnet?

Comment: I can't telnet, simply because telnet has been disabled. They are on the same subnet.